# Simplest Way to Add Time as "11:26" UTC+3 for HTML Page

Tags: javascript, html

How can I add the time stamp as "11:26" UTC+3 for HTML Page, javascript or another method that won't slow the page?

Right now I use:

```js
var clockID;
var yourTimeZoneFrom = +3.00;
var d = new Date();
var tzDifference = yourTimeZoneFrom * 60 + d.getTimezoneOffset();
var offset = tzDifference * 60 * 1000;

function UpdateClock() {
  var tDate = new Date(new Date().getTime() + offset);
  var in_hours = tDate.getHours()
  var in_minutes = tDate.getMinutes();
  var in_seconds = tDate.getSeconds();

  if (in_minutes < 10)
    in_minutes = '0' + in_minutes;
  if (in_seconds < 10)
    in_seconds = '0' + in_seconds;
  if (in_hours < 10)
    in_hours = '0' + in_hours;

  document.getElementById('timestamp').innerHTML = "" + in_hours + ":" + in_minutes + ":" + in_seconds;
}

function StartClock() {
  clockID = setInterval(UpdateClock, 500);
}

function KillClock() {
  clearTimeout(clockID);
}

window.onload = function() {
  StartClock();
}
```

```html
<div id="timestamp"></div>
```

Thanks for the answers in advance.

Comment: What is wrong with what you have?

Comment: You might find this useful for the future: http://phrogz.net/js/FormatDateTime_JS.txt

Comment: @EternalHour Nothing, but it seems like slowed the page a bit. I just look for faster solutions actually.

Comment: If you are looking for improvements to your code, hit up [Code Review on the StackExchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). ;-)

Comment: I think for Code Review the question would be acceptable, but you may want to change how it is worded, as we have a rule where asking for new code to be written is explicitly off-topic on CR. If you are looking for general improvements, then CR is the best place.

Comment: OK guys. Thank you so much. I am not good at java, that's the problem. I added the code just as a reference, it may be something else, faster.